# String representation of pandas.NaT is sometimes "nan" instead of "NaT"

Tags: python, pandas

When I convert `pandas.NaT` into a string the results is sometimes `"nan"` instead of `"NaT"`.

I am sorry but I am unable to reproduce this in an MWE with example data. Maybe this depends on the size of DataFrame? I am using `pandas==1.3.0`.

I create a string representation of a column holding datetime objects which some of them are `NaT` like this:

```
df['X'] = df.ZEIT_VON.apply(str)
```

Let's look into the result

```
>>> df_roh.loc[60:63, ['ZEIT_VON', 'X']]
   ZEIT_VON    X
60      NaT  NaT
61      NaT  NaT
62      NaT  nan
63      NaT  nan
```

You see the difference between row 61 and 62?

Here are some type information.

```
>>> df_roh.loc[60:63, ['ZEIT_VON', 'X']].dtypes
ZEIT_VON    datetime64[ns]
X                   object
dtype: object

>>> type(df_roh.loc[62, 'ZEIT_VON'])
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType'>
>>> type(df_roh.loc[61, 'ZEIT_VON'])
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType'>
```

Another try.

```
>>> str(df_roh.loc[61, 'ZEIT_VON'])
'NaT'
>>> str(df_roh.loc[62, 'ZEIT_VON'])
'NaT'
```

Comment: "I am sorry but I am unable to reproduce this in an MWE with example data." What happens if you make a new DataFrame using `df_roh.loc[60:63, ['ZEIT_VON']]`? What if you try dumping that DataFrame out and loading it again? If that reproduces the error, could you show the dump file as input? Alternately: what if you try starting with the process that generates your DataFrame, and modifying it to produce only the part of the data you're currently zooming in on? Can you reproduce the problem that way? If so, show us that modified process.

Comment: I tried all that you mentioned. But thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `df` is constructed from a concatenation of DataFrames where "X" column stored different dtype objects. Consider the example below:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'X':['2020-01-01', np.nan]})
a['X'] = pd.to_datetime(a['X'])
b = pd.DataFrame({'X':[np.nan, 'string']})
```

If you look at `a['X']`, it's a pandas datetime object with a `pd.NaT` value:

```
0   2020-01-01
1          NaT
Name: X, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and if you look at `b['X']`, it's object dtype with a `np.nan` value:

```
0       NaN
1    string
Name: X, dtype: object
```

Now, if we concatenate `a` and `b`, convert column to "X" string type:

```
ab = pd.concat((a,b))
out = ab['X'].astype(str)
```

we get a dtype object Series with both `NaT` and `nan` values:

```
0    2020-01-01 00:00:00
1                    NaT
0                    nan
1                 string
Name: X, dtype: object
```

Note that both should be recognized as nan values if you don't convert to strings. For example,

```
ab['X'].isna()
```

returns

```
0    False
1     True
0     True
1    False
Name: X, dtype: bool
```